# Find equation of a parabola when the area cut by a straight line and two intersection points are given.

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, quadratics, area

1. I have equation of a straight line $y = -\frac{0.45}{0.248}x - 1.1330645$
2. It intersects a quadratic function graph (parabloa) at two points (-0.652, 0.05) & (-0.9, 0.5)
3. I have the area bounded between them, it is 0.19.
   I need to know the equation of the quadratic function. 
   [image: The graph looks like this]
   This is what i tried,
   **$\int_{0.05}^{0.5}[{(-\frac{y+1.330645}{1.81451613}) - (ay^2+by+c)] dy=0.19}$**

Comment: Note that if the curve in the diagram is a parabola, then the equation is wrong. What you wrote is the equation of a parabola whose symmetry axis is vertical (parallel to $y$). Your axis of symmetry looks perpendicular top the given line.

Comment: @Andrei you are right. I think the parabola should be $x = ay^2+by+c$
So, is this the right way? **$\int_{-0.652}^{-0.9}{(-\frac{0.45}{0.245}x - 1.15306)dx - \int_{0.05}^{0.5}(ay^2+by+c) dy=0.19}$**

Comment: If that's the equation of the parabola, then the symmetry axis is horizontal. Is that want you want? Where is the problem coming from?

Comment: @Andrei I am an Engineer.It has been a long time since I did calculus.Everything is handled by a software this days, we don't use calculus often.It is a pressure distribution on a buried reinf. concrete pipe.The pressure distribution on the pipe side walls is parabolic (we call it heger pressure distribution,It is a given thing and I am trying to solve a certain portion of it which we call it A3 region, which is a parabola opened to the right and bounded by a straight line with the area given as A3 = 0.19 ). So inorder to know pressure at any point i need to know that parabolic function.

Comment: I will add an answer, because I can't put a picture in the comment.

Comment: Might I suggest moving the curve around, it's easy to reverse.  Set the turning point to zero that makes b'=0, then move it vertically so y'=0.  That should leave y'=(a')* (x')^2. .  Notice that you haven't changed the curve "shape" but the problem should be easier.  The parabola is symmetric, and convex.  I think a final trick is, use integration by parts of each side separately.  Of course, this must be done symbolically and then backtrack.  I will try it this way tomorrow if there are problems.

Answer (score 2):

**THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER**, but I can't post picture in the comment, and my clarification request is long.

You are not providing enough information. Look at the black line below $y=-x-m$, and the intersections with the red, green, and blue curves. The RGB curves all pass through two points on the line, and all are parabolas. The green one is the form $y=ax^2+bx+c$, with the symmetry axis vertical. The blue one is the form $x=ay^2+by+c$, with the symmetry axis horizontal. The red one is the form $$x+y=a(x-y)^2+b(x-y)+c$$
I choose this form, so that it's axis of symmetry is perpendicular to the original straight line. All colored curves are parabolas, and the parameters can be adjusted so that they will pass through the given points and the area is the given number. In principle there are an infinite numbers of parabolas that obey your given conditions. If you look at the picture above, I could draw the symmetric curves with respect to the straight line.

In order for your problem to have a unique solution, you need to specify the axis of symmetry and the position of the vertex with respect too the straight line. In your case, it seems like the axis of symmetry is perpendicular to the straight line in the middle of the two given points, and the vertex is below.

[image: parabolas]

Comment: I like your diagram, but, looks like i got lucky because mine was perfectly horizontal like the blue ones, I solved simultaneously and my equations is $x = 12.9275165615y^2 - 7.6612452199y - 0.3012565304$ and with the line $\frac{y+1.133064516}{-1.814516129}$ it gave me an area of 0.196 ≈ 0.19 For some reason still your image makes sense, but, I tried to solve the equation simultaneously and got the equation so, I am taking it as a unique solution.Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You have the line $ y = m x + b $ and two points $P = (P_x, P_y)$ and $Q = (Q_x, Q_y )$ on the parabola $ x = A y^2 + B y + C $ where $A,B,C$ are unknown, but it is assumed that $A \gt 0$.

The equation of the line can be written as $ x = \dfrac{1}{m}(y - b)$

The area is given as $A_0$ where

$A_0 = \displaystyle \int_{P_y}^{Q_y} \dfrac{1}{m}(y - b) - (A y^2 + B y + C) dy \\
= \dfrac{1}{ m} \left( \dfrac{1}{2} (Q_y^2 - P_y^2) - b (Q_y - P_y) \right) - \dfrac{1}{3} A (Q_y^3 - P_y^3) + \dfrac{1}{2} B (Q_y^2 - P_y^2) + C (Q_y - P_y) $

In addition, we have

$ A P_y^2 + B P_y  + C = P_x $

$ A Q_y^2 + B Q_y + C = Q_x $

Now it is a matter of substituting the given values for $m,b, P_x, P_y, Q_x, Q_y$ and solving the resulting $3 \times 3$ linear system for $A,B,C$.

Comment: sorry, it has been a long time since I did calculus, I think the parabola is $x=ay2+by+c$ so, is this the right way? $\int_{-0.652}^{-0.9}{(-\frac{0.45}{0.245}x - 1.15306)dx - \int_{0.05}^{0.5}(ay^2+by+c) dy=0.19}$ and shouldn't the sign of B and C after the integral be negative.

Comment: I've updated my solution.

Comment: In your general formula above, I made coefficient of B & C negative and I got three equations $-0.041625000A - 0.12375B - 0.45C = 0.545536658$, $0.0025A + 0.05B + 1C = -0.652$ and $0.25A + 0.5B + C = -0.9$ and by solving these, I got $A=12.9275165615$, $B=-7.6612452199$ and $C=-0.3012565304$ I tested the equation and it looks like the one i wanted and also area between$x = 12.9275165615y^2 - 7.6612452199y - 0.3012565304$ and $\frac{y+1.133064516}{-1.814516129}$ gives 0.196 which is ≈ 0.19 this works for me,but,we also made an assumption that the graph is opened exactly to x axis. Thank you

Comment: You must have an error in setting up the three equations or solving them.  The values for $A, B, C$ must give you an area of exactly $0.19$

Comment: because the decimals were tedious, I rounded a few digits off do you think this is too far from the exact solution? It is off by only 3.2%

Comment: Yes.  $3.2\%$ is too big.